# Worst case quicksort space complexity explanation

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I wanna show the worst-case scenario of Quicksort space complexity.

I was thinking about it and Quicksort does not use auxiliary arrays, it just creates some auxiliary variables on Partition sub-routine but it just manipulates the items in the array. So, my conclusion, obviously, was that it used O(n) space.

But searching on the internet I found that space complexity of Quicksort on the worst-case scenario is O(log n).

I just do not understand why on the worst case it takes less space than the input array?

ps.: I'm following "Introduction to Algorithms"'s book.

What I have already tried was to count all variables declarations on the algorithm.

```
QUICKSORT(A, p, r)
    if p < r
        q = partition(A, p, r)
        QUICKSORT(A, p, q - 1)
        QUICKSORT(A, q + 1, r)


PARTITION(A, p, r)
    x = A[r] // pivot
    i = p - 1
    for j = p to r - 1
        if A[j] <= x
            i = i + 1
            exchange A[i] with A[j]
    exchange A[i + 1] with A[r]
    return i + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In evaluating the space complexity, you don't count the input storage, but you count the stack depth.

In straight QuickSort, the partition can be quite unfavorable every time and only reduce the subarray by one element. Hence, the space complexity is *O(n)* ! (usually a catastrophy).

For this reason, it is important to recurse on the smallest subarray first and use tail recursion. This lowers the worst case to *O(Log n)*.

Comment: Let me see if I got it right. Quicksort is O(n lg n), the first N comes from the Partition subroutine, but the recursion has a stack of O(lg n), that is why its space complexity is O(lg n) and since the Partition is not recursive, it does not add to the stack and the space complexity? 

I don't know, I sounds wrong. The recursion takes O(n lg n) time (n from the Partition and lg n from the recursion itself), but why the stack is O(lg n) as well? It sounds like for all algorithm the space complexity will be the same as the time complexity.

Comment: @LeonardoBenicio: I said that the worst case space complexity is O(n). The temporal complexity cannot be smaller than the space complexity, but can exceed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement quicksort like this, then the worst case space complexity is O(n):

```
QUICKSORT(A, p, r)
    if p < r
        q = partition(A, p, r)
        QUICKSORT(A, p, q - 1)
        QUICKSORT(A, q + 1, r)
```

But real implementations of quicksort are never written this way.  They're written like this:

```
QUICKSORT(A, p, r)
    while p < r
        q = partition(A, p, r)
        if (q-p <= r-q)
            QUICKSORT(A, p, q - 1)
            p = q+1
        else
            QUICKSORT(A, q + 1, r)
            r = q-1
```

As @YvesDoust was saying, it's important to recurse on the smaller part, then loop (or tail-recurse, but that's another story) on the larger part.

This way the range of each recursive call is at most half the range of the caller, and the maximum depth is O(log n)

Comment: “it's important to recurse on the smaller part”.
How do we get one part smaller and another part larger? How partitioning function should be implemented to achieve that? In real implementations.

Comment: No, as in the implementation I wrote, you just check to see which part is smaller, and recurse on that one before looping to do the other one.

Comment: @cassandrad Imagine your input array is `[7,1,7,1,7,7,7]`. Your pivot element will be either `7` or `1`, so you'll always end up with one partition with 2 elements and one partition with 5 elements. The partition method doesn't always create (almost never creates) two equal-sized partitions.

Comment: yeah, I know its not the real world quicksort but I'm following the "Introduction to Algorithms"'s book (Thomas h. Cormem). That is my problem, I think in this implementation it would use O(n) space but I saw on the internet O(n lg n). I think the problem was I saw the space consumption of the real quicksort, not the book one. that is why I couldn't prove that it only uses O(log n) space.

Edit: Looking at your algorithm, it is almost the same. Your while doing the same as my if because it is a recursion.

And "if (q-p <= r-q)" does not interfere in the algorithm...

Answer (score 0):

In the worst case, the space complexity is O(n), not O(log n), that is when the partitioning is always unbalanced; for example, one partition is always of size k and the other partition is always of size n-k where k is a constant (such as 1, 2, or 3) and n is the size of the array to be partitioned in each round of the recursions.

In other words, in the worst case, in every round of recursions, there is always one partition of size <= k (a small value, such as 1, 2, or 3). In this case, the size of the other partition is linearly decreasing (by k). So, you needs to recurse O(n/k) rounds.

It would be illogical if, in worst-case scenario, you can recurse O(log n) rounds for space complexity but you need O(n) rounds for time complexity.